# Displaying wide character in hexadecimal hex shows unexpected result

Tags: c, utf-8, hex

I am trying to display a wide character in hexadecimal and it gives me unexpected results and it would be always like 2 digit hex and my code.

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include"wchar.h"
#include "locale.h"
int main(){
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t ch;
    wscanf (L"%lc",&ch);
    wprintf(L"%x \n",ch);
  return 0;
}
```

input : `Ω`

result: `0xea`

expected result : `0xcea9`

I changed `setlocale` several times but the results always be the same.

**notice**

When the input value is smaller than 1 byte it works as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert wide character to hex"? Could you give an example of a character and example of output you expect to see? `it gives me unexpected results`  What results exactly? Could you please add `#include` and `int main` - writing them for the 1000nd time is no fun?

Comment: Aside: `#include "stdlib.h"` (etc.) should be `#include <stdlib.h>` unless you have your own library versions to use instead of the supplied ones.

Comment: @kamilCuk ok i clarified my code could you give any help

Comment: @WeatherVane i tried this as well but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you should use `<..>` for including standard headers. The line `wprintf("%x", ch)` is invalid, cause it's most probably undefined behavior - `ch` is (possibly) not an `unsigned int`, you can't apply `%x` on it.

You are expecting that wide characters will be stored in UTF-8. Well, that wouldn't make much sense, they are not. Your program reads a *sequence* of bytes in *multibyte encoding* and that sequence of bytes is then converted (depending on locale) to the wide character encoding. The wide character encoding (usually) stays the same and should be UTF-32 on linux. Locale affects the way multibyte characters are converted to wide characters and back, not the representation of wide characters.

The following program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t ch;
    int cnt = wscanf(L"%lc",&ch);
    if (cnt != 1) { /* handle error */ abort(); }
    wprintf(L"%x\n", (unsigned int)ch);
    return 0;
}
```

On linux when inputted [Greek Capital Letter Omega Ω U+3A9](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+03A9) the program outputs `3a9`. What actually happens is that the terminal reads UTF-8 encoded character, so it reads *two* bytes `0xCE 0xA9`, then converts them to UTF-32 and stores the result in the wide character. You may convert the wide character from wide character encoding (UTF-32) to multibyte character encoding (UTF-8 should be default, but depends on locale) and print the bytes that represent the character in multibyte character encoding:

```
char tmp[MB_CUR_MAX];
int len = wctomb(tmp, ch);   // prefer wcrtomb
if (len < 0) { /* handle error */ abort(); }
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    wprintf(L"%hhx", (unsigned char)tmp[i]);
}
wprintf(L"\n");
```

That will output `cea9` on my platform.

Comment: sorry for my late response , so after many times of attempts i discovered that the problem is i am using windows therefore the  encoding system for windows is `English_United States.1252` and it's not possible to change it even if  i used set local at last i will consider your answer the correct one cause it gave me a hint ,thanks

Comment: Well, there is no omega letter in CP1252 encoding. Windows uses UTF-16 to represent wide characters. Ooch, so `wctomb` is failing, because it's not possible to represent the omega character from UTF-16 to multibyte encoding in CP1252.